# show an example model for Map<String,String> in swagger for java endpoint

Tags: swagger-ui

I have

```
@POST
@Path("/path-to-call")
@Timed
@ActionRequired("my path-to-call")
@ApiOperation("description of call")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processmyCall(Map<String, String> requestBody) throws Exception{
```

but swagger shows with `{}` as the model.

how do i tell it to show

```
{"val":"<data>","val":"<data>"}
```